# adding if / then equation to magento 1/2 custom option pricing

Tags: magento, logic

I am planning on using a csv pricing matrix to calculate height x width for curtains. There are multiple heading types in curtains (track or pole) for example that increase the price of the curtains.

I ideally would like the end user to select their heading type from one front end product (having different products for each heading type would be easy, but not ideal UX). I am finding it difficult to source an extension that would essentially work on multi csvs dependent on custom option selection and so I wondered if a custom option could add a fixed cost to this.

The problem I then have is the cost isn't fixed on the width. for example 
upto 800mm would add £3 to price, up to 1600 would add £17, upto 2400 would add £32 and so on.

I therefore think I need to add if/then to the custom option. I think I would need to add If eyelet heading selected then +17 to total. *update* I should add that as it is made to measure then the logic would need to include an if totalprice

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. The crazy idea I came with by reading your problem goes like this. Your problem is that in custom options you have to set ranges but the end user will choose exactly the dimensions.

So, you could easily hide the custom options, give the end user a text input with proper validation and then with jquery select the right magento option.

All this If I understood your problem correctly.

Anyway you should modify the product view.phtml based on your needs and find a way to work globally for all your products or you will end up with a code too difficult to maintain in the future.